# Why do I get error CS1660 when converting lambda expression

Tags: c#, powershell, delegates

I need to optimize and add functionality to Powershell scripts for collecting and reconciling information from multiple sources of different types.
These scripts are event-driven to be reactive and avoid polling.
Several of these sources are websockets.

To simplify things, I'd like to use the 'Websocket.Client' module (https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client).
Its use by Powershell is straightforward.
Its only weakness is that it doesn't generate events natively.

‘Websocket.Client’ can run external code when the client connects, disconnects or receives a message.
I want to use this code to fire events.

I wrote the following WebsocketClientExt class derived from the WebsocketClient class in ‘Websocket.Client’.

```
if (-not ("WebsocketClientExt" -as [type])) {
  $cp = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using Websocket.Client;
using Websocket.Client.Models;

public class WebsocketClientExt : WebsocketClient {
  
  public event EventHandler<DisconnectionInfo> Disconnection;
  
  public WebsocketClientExt( Uri url ): base(url) { }
  
  public void SubscribeEvents () {
    DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info => Disconnection?.Invoke(this, info));
  }
    
}
"@
  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cp -ReferencedAssemblies @( 'Websocket.Client', 'System.Net.WebSockets', 'System.Net.WebSockets.Client' )
}
```

I do not understand why the compiler generates the error CS1660 when Powershell executes the above script.

```
Add-Type:
Line |
  22 |      Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cp -ReferencedAssemblies @( 'Websocket. …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | (15,41): error CS1660: Impossible de convertir expression lambda en type 'IObserver<DisconnectionInfo>', car il ne s'agit pas d'un type délégué
        DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info => Disconnection?.Invoke(this, info));
```

In english : error CS1660: Unable to convert lambda expression to 'IObserver' type, as it's not a delegated type
DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info => Disconnection?.Invoke(this, info));

As far as I know EventHandler is a delegate … thus, why this error ?

Comment: Have you checked what version of the library is used?

Comment: Powershell is version 7 and Websocket.Client uses net7.

Comment: And `Websocket.Client` itself has what version?

Comment: 4.7.0. I rebuilt Websocket.Client from source to make it compatible with net7.

Comment: `Websocket.Client` is compatable with .NET 7 as far as I can see. What makes you think it is not?

Comment: the source on github is compatible with net7. But the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Websocket.Client is not.

Comment: The nuget package is compatible with .NET 7. Note that the nuget package is supporting [.NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1 specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0). And .NET 7 adheres to the .NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1 spec. Therefore, the nuget package supporting .NET Standard 2.0/2.1 makes it compatible with .NET 7.

Comment: nuget is compatible with .NET 7 since it is supporting .NET Standard.

Comment: Also, don't get confused regarding events and event handlers here. As far as i can tell, `WebsocketClient.DisconnectionHappened` is a property of type `IObservable<DisconnectionInfo>`. This is not a .NET event, so you wondering about EventHandler(s) is a red herring.

Comment: `IObservable<T>.Subscribe` method expects not a delegate/lambda expression, it expects an `IObserver<T>` being passed to it. Hence the error you see, because delegates are not convertible to the `IObserver<T>` interface.

Comment: I don't know, though, how you would wrap a delegate (like your lambda expression) into an `IObserver<DisconnectionInfo>` instance to pass it to the`IObservable<DisconnectionInfo>.Subscribe` method. Perhaps there is some factory or convenience method in the library you are using that could make this easy. Or perhaps not. As i said, i don't know :-(

Comment: I did not know ... However, I retried with the netstandard2.1 version of the dll in nuget package and the result/error is the same.

Comment: Yes of course the error is the same, because the error is unrelated to supported or unsupported .NET versions. The error is about what your code is trying to pass to the Subscribe method (see my previous comments)

Comment: I was writing at the same time... Ok, I understand that. But how could I do to fire event from the .Subscribe property (it is not a method but a property of the WebsocketClient class).

Comment: "_Subscribe property (it is not a method but a property of the WebsocketClient class_" No! Subscribe is obviously a method; note the parantheses in `DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(...)`. DisconnectionHappened is a property of WebsocketClient, holding an instance implementing `IObserver<DisconnectionInfo>`. And that instance has a method named Subscribe (by virtue of implementing `IObserver<DisconnectionInfo>`) that your code is attempting to call.

Comment: This is the example from github page of Websocket-Client : client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
        Log.Information($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));

Comment: I understand that .Subscibe is a method (my misunderstanding). I performed another test by replacing the event firing Disconnection?... with Log.Information... of the above example and I get the same result/error. Why is it working in the example and not working in my derived class ?

Comment: With respect to the example you mentioned, check the dependencies of that example and the namespaces it is using in its source files. It almost feels to me that either some dependency or a namespace in the library includes Subscribe extension methods accepting delegate types, and which the example you mentioned uses but your own project is not using...

Comment: Look at the WebSocketClient readme.md. It mentions that it uses Rx.NET. Searching the github repo of Rx.NET for Subscribe extension methods yields this: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Freactive+Subscribe%3CT%3E%28this&type=code. Therefore, try adding the Rx.NET dependency to the `Add-Type` command line and see where it gets you...

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all for your help, each one gave me a part of the solution.

Following the advise of @EyesShriveledToRaisins I found that using System.Reactive.Linq and using System.Reactive.Subjects were missing in the code.
The System.Reactive assembly is required to work with observable events.

Now the script part is

```
if (-not ("WebsocketClientExt" -as [type])) {
    $cp = @"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using Websocket.Client;
using Websocket.Client.Models;

public class WebsocketClientExt : WebsocketClient {
    
    public event EventHandler<ReconnectionInfo> Connected;
    public event EventHandler<ResponseMessage> Received;
    public event EventHandler<DisconnectionInfo> Disconnected;
    
    public WebsocketClientExt( Uri url ): base(url) { }
    
    public void SubscribeEvents () {
        ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(c => Connected?.Invoke(this, c));
        MessageReceived.Subscribe(m => Received?.Invoke(this, m));
        DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(d => Disconnected?.Invoke(this, d));
    }
    
}
"@
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cp -ReferencedAssemblies @( 'Websocket.Client', 'System.Net.WebSockets', 'System.Net.WebSockets.Client', 'netstandard', 'System.Reactive' )
}
```

Tested and working fine.